# Python: redirection doesn't work on os.system

Tags: python, networking

I'm trying to do a quick ping check over some switches.
I start a while loop, iterating through all of them which are whithin a file.
In the while loop, I call a function called pings, the only thing it does is ping the current IP and redirect with ">" the output to a file called ping.txt, After that, another function take it, format it right and insert into a db.

As long as I've tried, it only inserts the last ping.

I've debugged it, it takes the ip into the pings function every time, but only redirect to the file the last ping.

For simplicity I've taken only the affected parts of the code and get it into file (already tried it on new file and didn't work).

```
class Network(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def pings(self,ip):
        os.system("ping -c 1 {}>ping.txt".format(ip))   

class FullPass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def pings(self, ip, archivo):
        net = Network()
        net.pings(ip)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    full = FullPass()
    f = open('switches.txt')
    ip = f.readline()
    while ip != "":
        full.pings(ip, 'ping.txt')
        ip = f.readline()
```

Comment: To be fair, it is not easy to understand what exactly your problem is. If `ping.txt` is intended as temporary storage only, then what do you mean by `it only inserts the last ping.`? Inserts where? The database? Inserts what? Just the last line of the ping command output? Please try to clarifay your question.

Comment: Yes, I have to be more concise, ping.txt is a file which stores only one ping result, renewing its content on every ip change. After redirecting only one output, it should pass to another function, which formats it, and then insert it into a db.
So, one insert for each ip, to keep track of the alive state and latency.
It's supposed to be at least 15 inserts on the whole loop.
The point is, when doing the > redirection, it doesn't store the ping result, even temporary, I've debugged it. Only stores the last ip in the list.

Comment: Ah, OK .. that makes it clearer. Do you need that file for anything else than to capture each iteration's output? If not, you could use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) or [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) with `capture_output=True` on Python >= 3.5 to get the command output in your script directly without having to manage that temp file.

Comment: Great! You might want to create an answer with your solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, the final way is like this:

```
 def command(self, ip, file, com): 
    with open(file, 'a') as outfile: 
        subprocess.call([com+ip[:-1]], stdout=outfile, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use '>>' instead of '>'. Two signs do an append while one sign truncates the target before writing to it.

Comment: Yes, that's the point, for each switch, empty the .txt file, puts the new info there, and then go through the format and insert functions.
The Full estructure is:
ping > ping.txt -> format -> insert
for each switch